# Preserving old file when editing object and not uploading a new one on Django form

Tags: django

I have a Player class that uses a ForeignKey to a Photo object for purposes of attaching a mugshot. My problem is that when I edit a player who has a mugshot and I don't upload a new one, the old mugshot is getting detached from the Player object. There must be something wrong with my logic.

```
class Player( models.Model ):
    ...
    mugshot = models.ForeignKey( 'content.Photo', null=True, blank=True )
    ...
```

My PlayerForm class looks like this:

```
class PlayerForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    ...
    mugshot = forms.FileField( widget=forms.FileInput(), required=False )
    ...

    def save(self, commit=True, request=None, user=None):
        player = super( PlayerForm, self ).save( commit=False )

        if commit:
            player.save()

        return player
```

In my edit view, I update the player, then check for the existence of a file upload to see whether or not to replace the mugshot.

```
def edit_player( request, team_season_id, player_id ):
    team_season = get_object_or_404( TeamSeasonConference, pk=team_season_id )
    player = get_object_or_404( Player, pk=player_id )

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'cancel' not in request.POST:
        player_form = PlayerForm( request.POST, instance=player )

        if player_form.is_valid():
            updated_player = player_form.save(True)

            if request.FILES: # if sent a file
                file_data = request.FILES['mugshot']
                picture = Photo.objects.create( # create a photo object with that file
                name = player_form.cleaned_data['first_name'] + ' ' + player_form.cleaned_data['last_name'], # and give it the name of the player you're adding
                cutline = '',
                file = file_data,
                source = '',
            )
        else:
            picture = player.mugshot; # keep the old one

        updated_player.mugshot = picture
        updated_player.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight reworking should fix the problem:

```
def edit_player( request, team_season_id, player_id ):
team_season = get_object_or_404( TeamSeasonConference, pk=team_season_id )
player = get_object_or_404( Player, pk=player_id )

if request.method == 'POST' and 'cancel' not in request.POST:
    player_form = PlayerForm( request.POST, instance=player )

    if player_form.is_valid():
        updated_player = player_form.save(True)

        if request.FILES: # if sent a file
            file_data = request.FILES['mugshot']
            picture = Photo.objects.create( # create a photo object with that file
                name = player_form.cleaned_data['first_name'] + ' ' + player_form.cleaned_data['last_name'], # and give it the name of the player you're adding
                cutline = '',
                file = file_data,
                source = '',
            )

            # You only need to save again if there is a picture
            updated_player.mugshot = picture
            updated_player.save()
```

Also, your form needs to exclude the existing mugshot:

```
class PlayerForm( forms.ModelForm ):

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        exclude = ('mugshot',)

    def save(self, ...):
        #as it was before
```

Comment: would that safely keep any previously connected photo to the Player model? If in editing an existing player, the user does not upload a file, wouldn't the form save remove the previously attached photo?

Comment: I forgot to add the code for the new form! By exluding the existing mugshot from the form, you ensure that the existing foreign key will not be modified unless you do it manually, to the instance. We only do this when a new mugshot is uploaded.